# how to add dom4j dependecy in maven pom with spring boot

Tags: java, maven, dom4j

I want to use dom4j to parse xml string. But when I add dom4j dependency in pom file, my dev tool(Eeclipse) prompt errors below:
[image]
I tried to refresh project and maven's update project, the errors still occured. If remove the dependency, all of errors disappear, also dom4j cannot use.

- Eclipse version:

  Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
  Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)
  Build id: 20180619-1200
- POM file:

  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      4.0.0

  ```
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
          <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
  ```
- Maven Version:
  [image]

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the project and Maven -> Update Project?  Every time the pom is changed, this needs to be run.

Comment: Yes, I have tried Maven->Update project and also refresh project, but the errors still occur.@karen

Comment: If you have maven installed on your computer try "mvn install"  to install any missing packages (further details [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

Comment: First think is: Try to build your project on plain command line...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it through a whole day working, the fix steps are:
1. the first line of errors prompt in eclipse is : fail to read artifact descriptor for xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01.(the first capture image of the question)
2. I assumed that something are wrong with xml-apis in maven repository, so I find the directory of xml-apis in maven repository and remove them all
3. After that, I use Maven->Update project in eclipse, the errors run away.

I think the reason is: some files of xml-apis were damaged.